# Move visibility of UIScrollView area automatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiscrollview

I want to make my view automatically moving up if keyboard appears. Already use apple's code [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009542-CH5-SW7) and it works well.

This is how I manage my object, so I create a `UIScrollView` that covers `UIView`. This `UIView` consists of `UITextField` and `UIButton`.

[image: Document Outline]

This is how I adjust my view when keyboard appears.

```
#pragma mark - Keyboard Handling

// Call this method somewhere in your view controller setup code.
- (void)registerForKeyboardNotifications
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWasShown:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWillBeHidden:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];

}

// Called when the UIKeyboardDidShowNotification is sent.
- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];
    CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;

    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, kbSize.height, 0.0);
    _scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets;
    _scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;

    // If active text field is hidden by keyboard, scroll it so it's visible
    // Your app might not need or want this behavior.
    CGRect aRect = self.view.frame;
    aRect.size.height -= kbSize.height;
    if (!CGRectContainsPoint(aRect, _mainView.frame.origin) ) {
        [self.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:_mainView.frame animated:YES];
    }
}

// Called when the UIKeyboardWillHideNotification is sent
- (void)keyboardWillBeHidden:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
    _scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets;
    _scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;
}
```

But I think there is a point that make that weird. When keyboard showed up, it scrolls and my `UITextField` become visible. But I thought it was too tight.

[image: Result]

In my opinion, it would be better if my `UITextField` moving up a little bit. My question is, how can I set its scroll visibility? It looks like some variable should be added with some constant here

```
CGRect aRect = self.view.frame;
aRect.size.height -= kbSize.height;
if (!CGRectContainsPoint(aRect, _mainView.frame.origin) ) {
    [self.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:_mainView.frame animated:YES];
}
```

**Note**: 
Result that I wanted
[image: Expectation]

Thank you so much, a little hint would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved**

I solved this by manage its content inset by adding some number. 
In `keyboardWasShown:`, I added its content inset by height of my textfield and button. Let say it was 100 total, so this is it.

```
UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, kbSize.height+100, 0.0);
```

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution would be to move your view (or scrollview) up when keyboard opens.

```
- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification*)notification{
    [self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0,-100, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)]; // where 100 is the offset
    [self.view setNeedsDisplay];

}

- (void)keyBoardWillHide:(NSNotification*)notification{
    [self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    [self.view setNeedsDisplay];
}
```